# How to count the number of identical letters in a string in RPG

Tags: rpgle, rpg

I would like to count the number of 'i' in the name 'olivia' but I have the impression that my condition is not valid?

How to do charAt in RPG 4 please?

```
FOR i = 1 to %len(name);
  IF %check(name : letter) = 0;
    count += 1;

  ENDIF;

ENDFOR;
```

Here is the complete code:

```
**free

dcl-s name        varchar(50);
dcl-s letter      char(1);
dcl-s count       packed(2:0);
dcl-s i           packed(3:0);
dcl-s waitInput   char(1);
dcl-s message     varchar(50);

name = 'olivia';
letter = 'i';
count = 0;

FOR i = 1 to %len(name);
  IF %check(name : letter) = 0;
    count += 1;

  ENDIF;

ENDFOR;

message = 'The name ' + %char(name) + ' has ' + %char(count) + 'time(s) the letter ' + (letter) ;
dsply message '' waitInput;

*INLR = *on;
```

Comment: What is the context? Why is it tagged "ibm-cloud"?

Comment: @data_henrik: Sorry, it'is an error. I edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IF %check(name : letter) = 0;
```

=>

```
 IF %subst(name :i:1) = letter;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works ! Why are you using a `1` here `name:i:1`?

Comment: you used a loop to check each character, "letter" is one character so you must compare only 1 char at a time     %SUBST(string:start{:length})

Comment: Thank you Dam for your explanations.